# Running Play service from Gradle

Tags: gradle, playframework

I am attempting to use a Gradle task to run a Play service, but I'm finding the Gradle task will hang (presumably waiting for a return value from the Play bootstrap script).

What I'm doing from the Play side is simply:

```
sbt dist
```

Which produces a .zip distribution (like 'myproject.zip'), which I then expand where I want to run this service from.

On the Gradle side, I was thinking I would do something like this:

```
task start(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "myproject/bin"
    commandLine './myproject'
}
```

This does indeed start up the Play service just fine, but the Gradle task will hang indefinitely (until you do a control+C).

The most obvious thing that came to mind to try was something like:

```
task start(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "myproject/bin"
    commandLine 'nohup ./myproject &'
}
```

But that ends in a dead end:

```
Execution failed for task ':start'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'nohup ./playservicetemplate &''
```

It seems like this is a really common use case, so I'm wondering if there is an obvious solution that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

There is perhaps a more Gradle-ish way to do this, but I solved it by leveraging ProcessBuilder.  My new task looks like:

```
task start {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("./myproject")
    builder.directory(new File("myproject/bin"))
    builder.start()
}
```

Obviously, you can get a lot fancier with this (a quick Google of 'java processbuilder' will net you pages upon pages of examples), but this will do the trick for my purposes.